# Can I map a List of Id's to a List of Entities with that Id at the model level in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, entity-relationship

I have a Pets class:

```
public class Pets {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  
  public List<int> DogIds { get; set; }
  public virtual List<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a Dog class:

```
public class Dog {
  int Id { get; set; }

  // Whatever else
}
```

what I would like to be able to do is to provide a list of Dog Id's to the Pets controller...

```
{ DogIds: [2,3,5] }
```

...where I link to existing Dogs in my database by the list of DogIds, and then have Entity Framework "automatically" link those actual entities in the Dogs List so that `myPets.Dogs.First()` will actually give me the dog with the provided id 2.

I've successfully done this with single entities by having a `public int DogId` with a `public Dog Dog` by defining

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Pets>()
  .HasOne(p => p.Dog)
  .WithMany()
  .HasForeignKey(p => p.DogId);
```

and then telling my controller

```
Pets pets = _context.Pets.Include(b => b.Dog).FirstOrDefault();
```

this will give me an actual Entity when I call `pets.Dog`

But in the case of many `DogIds` each to their own single `Dog` I'm really not sure how to describe this relationship, so that `_context.Pets.Include(b => b.Dog).FirstOrDefault().Dogs` gives me something other than `[]`.

Is this still technically a one to one relationship, and how do I define the type of relationship this is to actually make this work?

I've seen a lot of examples of how to do this at the query level, but I'd really like to leverage the framework here to do the heavy lifting if it's possible.

Comment: [One-to-many relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many) in EF Core.